# how to create a custom simple moving average in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, moving-average

I'd like to create a simple moving average please in Pine for Tradingview.

The moving average is the average of: 13-period high, 13-period low, 65-period high and 65-period low. (so these 4 numbers divided by 4)

Can somebody please help?

Thank you,
CT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator("myavg", overlay = true)

h13 = ta.highest(high, 13)
l13 = ta.lowest(low, 13)
h65 = ta.highest(high, 65)
l65 = ta.lowest(low, 65)

myAvg = math.avg(h13, l13, h65, l65)

plot(myAvg)
```